Amazon Ads API Discrepancy with Amazon Ads Dashboard
I'm trying to fetch my amazon ads campaigns data to create automation data for my clients. However, when I fetch data, there is slightly discrepancy between API's result and amazon ads dashboard data. I'm trying to fetch data that's on sponsored ads > single country (usa) . i tried to use the column name as sales7d, sales14d, sales30d. But none of them got the correct value.
I have tried to use different type of groupby such as campaigns, adgroup, but still couldnt get the correct values. I also double checked the timezone but it didnt help as well. is there any suggestions about this case?
Here is my request body , headers and endpoint;
url = "https://advertising-api.amazon.com/reporting/reports"

request_body = {
    "name": report_name,
    "startDate": start_date,
    "endDate": end_date,
    "configuration": {
        "adProduct": "SPONSORED_PRODUCTS",
        "groupBy": ["adGroup"],
        "reportTypeId": "spCampaigns",
        "timeUnit": "DAILY",
        "columns": ["date", "sales30d"],
        "format": "GZIP_JSON"
    }
}
headers = {
    "Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientId": CLIENT_ID,
    "Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope": profile_id,
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"

I have tried different type of groupby and reportTypeId and column names.
I want to fetch correct value with APIs

Check this: https://advertising.amazon.com/help/GX7KDKHMWQYMJ385

For sponsored brands and sponsored display, use column name sales (it is 14d attributtion window)
For sponsored products check advertiser type

if it is seller - use sales7d
if it is vendor or author - use sales14d
You request body should look like this if advertiser type is seller:



`
        "name": "report",
        "startDate": since,
        "endDate": until,
        "configuration": {
            "adProduct": ad_product,
            "groupBy": ["campaign"],
            "columns": [
                "date",
                "campaignId",
                "impressions",
                "clicks",
                "cost",
                "sales7d" if ad_product == AdType.SPONSORED_PRODUCTS else "sales",
                "purchases7d" if ad_product == AdType.SPONSORED_PRODUCTS else "purchases",
            ],
            "reportTypeId": report_type_id,
            "timeUnit": "DAILY",
            "format": "GZIP_JSON",
        },

    `

